# Is it safe to leave my luggage in a baggage deposit?

Tags: security, luggage-storage, prg

I'm spending 2 days in Prague, and I'd like to leave my huge bag (with my laptop) in the Prague airport baggage deposit.

Is it safe to do that (theft-wise) or should I always be carrying my valuables?

Comment: I forgot to presice. I'm thinking about theft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, it's safe - keeping your bags safe is their only job!

I've heard of thefts from bags by baggage handlers at airports, by other travellers, even by hostel staff. I've *never*, anywhere in the world, heard of anybody having something stolen from a bag left in an accredited/official left luggage operation at an airport or train station.

And as for why, this business is usually basically a licence to print money (monopoly + customers in a hurry with money to spare), so they don't need to steal your dirty underwear to make a profit!